# How do i get the name of the author who is using a modal?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a password protected notes command for my bot where the user can enter their password and a note and it gets stored in a txt file

Im trying to get the `display_name` of the user who was in the modal.
Despite looking everywhere I've been unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my Code

```
@Client.tree.command(name="add", description="Adds a new note")
async def add(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    
    file_name = f"{interaction.user.name}.txt"
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have a personal Notes file.")
        return
    

class Add(ui.Modal, title='Add Note'):
    Password = ui.TextInput(label='Enter password')
    Note = ui.TextInput(label='Enter your Note', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph)
    
    #####I want the name of the user in the curly brackets in the next line#####
    with open(f'{}.txt','r') as file:
      pwd = file.readline()
    print(ui.Member.display_name)
  
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
      if Password != pwd:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'You entered a wrong password', ephemeral=True)
      else:
        with open(f'{file_name}','a') as file:
          file.write(Note)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Note Added', ephemeral=True)
```

I tried `ui.interaction.display_name` and several other methods I thought would work to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name from the `Interaction` instance, as you've figured out in the code above. If you want to access it in the Modal, but before submission (e.g., in the `__init__`), you add it as an `__init__` argument & pass it in. A modal is just a class, so basic OOP principles work just fine.